# Pull order data from WC_order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've seen things like:

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$email = $order->billing_email;

But where can I find a list of all of the attributes I can pull from an order? I've been searching for what seems like forever, scouring the documentation and I cannot find this seemingly very simple answer. I want to be able to pull various pieces of information from the order.

Comment: Check the entry in the `wp_postmeta` table. You can use the `get_post_meta` function to get any of the meta information stored in there. billing_email is stored as `_billing_email`

Comment: I'm sorry but this is rather vague.